# Selenium Python: execute_script is executing only once in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I want to perform following task 3 times without closing browser.
Open Google.com in a Tab.
Open New Tab 
Then close tab containing Google.com
Open Google.com in previous newly opened tab.

I am using following code to open new tab:

```
browser.execute_script("window.open('', 'new_tab')")
```

But when executed in a loop it only gets executed once.

I have printed Number of Window Handles which suggests that execute_script is executed only once.

My Full Code:

```
cpath="C:/Users/Gupta Niwas/Downloads/Softwares/Browsers/Drivers/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
#browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=fpath)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,executable_path=cpath)


for i in range(3):

    browser.get("https://google.com")
    print(len(browser.window_handles))

    print("current:",browser.current_window_handle)

    browser.execute_script("window.open('', 'new_tab')")

    print(len(browser.window_handles))
    next_tab=browser.window_handles[len(browser.window_handles)-1]
    print(next_tab)
    print(browser.title)
    browser.close()
    print(len(browser.window_handles))

    browser.switch_to_window(next_tab)
    browser.delete_all_cookies()
```

On the 2nd loop it throws an Exception:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Gupta Niwas/Downloads/Programming/Projects/Mi/temp5.py', 

wdir='C:/Users/Gupta Niwas/Downloads/Programming/Projects/Mi')
1
current: CDwindow-75E62D95A2A8A7808C5AC369A8070641
2
CDwindow-F1C8AFC0E5742A2E55CEA17FCD951D1D
Google
1
1
current: CDwindow-F1C8AFC0E5742A2E55CEA17FCD951D1D
1
CDwindow-F1C8AFC0E5742A2E55CEA17FCD951D1D
Google
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-12046950abfa>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Gupta Niwas/Downloads/Programming/Projects/Mi/temp5.py', wdir='C:/Users/Gupta Niwas/Downloads/Programming/Projects/Mi')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Gupta Niwas/Downloads/Programming/Projects/Mi/temp5.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(len(browser.window_handles))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 719, in window_handles
    return self.execute(Command.GET_WINDOW_HANDLES)['value']

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here is a problem:

```
next_tab = browser.window_handles[len(browser.window_handles)-1]
```

Your `next_tab` is getting a current window reference. And when you are closing current window:

```
browser.close()
```

You cannot switch to `next_tab`, because it is not exists. I suggest you to debug your code and find out which value should you have in `browser.window_handles[?]`

Comment: I am passing the window handle of Last Tab i.e. which is newly created. If you run my code I have added print statements to print number of Windows at required points. Then you can see that in loop 2 the number of window handles doesn't increase to 2.

Comment: It would be nice if you post the full output you getting, I'm not able to execute the code now.